# Is it possible to dynamically set currentTime of a video without calling onSeeked?

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to use JavaScript to change the currentTime property of a video element. The property assignment is pretty simple and works. I am also listening for seek changes by the video. My problem is that whenever the currentTime property is assigned programmatically, both the onseeking and onseeked methods are called. My reason for listening for the seeks is to capture ONLY seek events generated by the user and not the code. Similar code to what I've tried so far is as follows:

```
var video = document.getElementById('vidi'); 

var isUser = false;

video.onseeking = function(){
 console.log("Seeking");
isUser = true;
};


video.onseeked = function() {
if(isUser){
    console.log("foo foo foo");
    isUser = false;
    }
};

video.currentTime = 600;
```

is it possible to only capture user generated seeks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you carefully alter and change `video.onseeking` and `video.onseeked` at the right time, you can distinguish user seeks/seeked vs programmatically-generated seeking/seeked (which I've simulated with the `do_non_user_seek()` function below).

The general idea is that when doing a non-user seek, first set `video.seeked` to point to a function `non_user_seeked()` which gets called automatically at the completion of the non-user seek, at which point it sets `video.onseeking` and `video.onseeked` back to their original `user_seeking()` and `user_seeked()` values.

You now have several functions which get called depending on whether the seek was user-invoked, and can distinguish between them accordingly. See the `console.log()` results for details of which gets called when.

```js
<script>

var video = document.getElementById('vidi'); 
video.onseeking = user_seeking;
video.onseeked = user_seeked;

function do_non_user_seek() {
  console.log( 'do_non_user_seek()' )
  video.onseeking = non_user_seeking;
  video.onseeked = non_user_seeked;
  video.currentTime = 600;
}

function user_seeking() {
  console.log( "user seeking")
}

function user_seeked() {
  console.log( "user seeked")
}

function non_user_seeking() {
  console.log( "non-user seeking")
}

function non_user_seeked() {
  video.onseeking = user_seeking;
  video.onseeked = user_seeked;
  console.log( "non-user seeked")
}

</script>
```

```html
<video width="400" controls id="vidi">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<button onclick="do_non_user_seek()">Seek (non-user)</button>
```